# lmer gives -Inf for logLik when weighting is included

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, weights

I have been trying to improve the residual distributions of a dataset with exponential decay data, using weights.
The data is decaying leaf mass, where we knew the initial masses in each sample, which were then allowed to decay over time and then remeasured at different time points (each bag only remeasured once). This means variances are very small for large masses and large for small masses (because variance accumulates over time). To correct this i have simply included a weighting parameter that is proportional to the mass of the sample (increased residual weight for large values and decreased residual weight for small values).

```
bags$weightvar <- abs(bags$mass_end)
```

There are three fixed effects: forest type, growth form and time. The data also has two crossed random effects, species and site, hence the need for `lmer()`.

The model formulation is thus:

```
lmm1w <- lmer(log(mass_end / mass_begin) ~ foresttype * growthform * time +
                                           (1 | species) + (1 | site),
              data=bags, weights=weightvar)
```

When i run this model, it does generate better residual properties. However, when i want to compare this model against the model without weights, lmm1, using anova(lmm1,lmm1w), i get the following:

```
Data: bags
Models:
lmm1: mass_ratio_log ~ foresttype * growthform * time + (1 | species) + 
lmm1:     (1 | site)
lmm1w: mass_ratio_log ~ foresttype * growthform * (time) + (1 | species) + 
lmm1w:     (1 | site)
      Df  AIC  BIC logLik deviance Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
lmm1  15 2082 2151  -1026     2052                        
lmm1w 15  Inf  Inf   -Inf      Inf     0      0          1
```

My Question: 
Why is `lmer()` generating `Inf` for the log likelihood of the weighted model? (Assuming i have not made a simple mistake.)

I have used nested comparisons with `lme()` before without `Inf` being generated. Also, `lme()` assigns the weighting an additional parameter `df`, which does not seem to happen in the `lmer()` output.

thanks very much!

Kyle

Answer (score 0):

Writing this as kind of an extended comment, firstly:

```
abs(bags$mass_end)
```

If mass_end can be negative, how did you take the log? This doesn't quite make sense, and in your formula, you called `mass_ratio_log` and did not show how this is derived.

To answer your question, you get a Inf in logLik most likely due to zero in your weights, for example, we simulate something like your data:

```
library(lme4)
set.seed(1000)
data = data.frame(mass_begin = rnorm(100,40,5))
data$mass_end = data$mass_begin - rnorm(100,20,5)
data$foresttype = sample(letters[1:2],100,replace=TRUE)
data$site = sample(LETTERS[3:4],100,replace=TRUE)
data$mass_ratio_log = log(data$mass_end/data$mass_begin)
data$weightvar <- abs(data$mass_end)
```

This works fine:

```
logLik(lmer(mass_ratio_log ~ foresttype  + (1|site),data=data,weights=weightvar))
'log Lik.' -16.19883 (df=4)
```

Make one of the weights zero:

```
data$weightvar[1] = 0
logLik(lmer(mass_ratio_log ~ foresttype  + (1|site),data=data,weights=weightvar))
'log Lik.' -Inf (df=4)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the insightful answer. There were indeed zero values in mass_end. (Also: your description of mass_ratio_log was correct; i will try to be more careful about providing sufficient information in future.)